# How to pass data between web pages MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I’m developing my first Web application using C# MVC/Javascript and was wondering how to handle authentication .

My AccountController uses something like this.

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
```

I store the username and email in a cookie

Now I need to pull data from my database for the authenticated user…. So I use the cookie values

I feel like this is the wrong way to pass the current user info between web pages for several reasons:

For example what if the user disabled cookies in their browser.
Or there is a risk of exposing  sensitive cookie data in the cookies.

My question is:

What’s the best way for passing user authentication data between web pages?

What the industry standards?

Comment: Did you modify the `MembershipProvider` that MVC 3 implement by default?

Comment: Once a user goes to the log in page you should encrypt your page, and all subsequent pages, with SSL (as in HTTPS).  This is becoming standard (see google).  As web pages are stateless you need a method of storing "Who" in the local browser. This information is then passed back and forth in the request. The cookie is the approach taken. The cookie data is encrypted and if its transport is HTTPS then it’s harder for a hacker to see the cookie.